# How to download a repo ZIP and get its history to push and pull to remote?

Tags: git, git-remote

There are a couple of ZIP archives of a few repositories. I have even made a few changes in couple of them.

I want to link it to the remote repos now to push and pull with the appropriate remotes.

Have tried doing this:

1. Create a repo:

```
$ cd path/to/your/local/directory
$ git init # make it a git repository
$ git checkout -b my_awesome_branch # checkout to a new branch containing your local changes
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m 'This should be a Message describing your local changes'
```

2. Add a remote:

```
$ git remote add my_awesome_upstream <your-upstream-git-repository-url>
$ git remote -v # To list remotes, and see if your remote is added correctly
$ git push my_awesome_upstream my_awesome_branch
```

But this doesn't have the old history of the branches and only creates a fresh branch.

I tried pulling an existing branch into my new branch but that gives `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories` even the `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` can't correct.

---

You might ask why not just clone the repo:

1. The clone doesnt seem to work for one of existing branches. Few files are not being cloned. Haven't figured out why. So ZIP download is able to get them.
2. Like after making file changes I have wondered a few times if this was possible and want to know for odd situations like above.

So.... is there a safe way to convert ZIP archives of a git repo to continue working on them?

Comment: When in your procedures do you download and unpack a Zip archive, and where to? And what kind of Zip archive is that? One of a snapshot of the repository or one that contains the history, too? (If you don't know: Where do you get it from?)

Comment: Also, could it be that it's a repo that uses [tag:git-lfs]?

Comment: @das-g The "download as ZIP" option in gitlab hosted in my organisation. not sure if it contains the history or not. Not sure of git-lfs but it has our code in it. Thought the issues with clone command was from my end so tried to get a ZIP

Comment: No, the Zip available through GitLab's "Download" > "Download source code" > "zip" does **not** contain the history. Same goes for the other archive formats available there, as well as the corresponding functionality on GitHub.